# 603,550 Jews at Sinai and 603,550 Jews Entering Promised Land?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, number, kabbalat-hatorah, har-sinai

Why in [Exodus 38:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.38.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) does it say there were 603,550 men over age 20, and then in [Numbers 1:46](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.1.46?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) the exact same number (603,550) is again listed?

Didn’t all the Jews of the generation in Exodus all die out because of the golden calf? How could there be the same exact number a whole generation later?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Ben and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Answers below, but I don't get the question. All the Jews of that generation died out (not because of the golden calf, because of the sin of the spies). A new generation was born and grew up and had fairly similar numbers.

Answer (score 5):

As Alex [shared](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100540/11501) this was the same generation: the first census was before the Tabernacle was built since the half-shekels used for the count were used for the sockets of the structure, the second was seven months later.

Still Artscroll picks up on the fact the numbers are similar and brings 3 opinions

- **Rashi** ([Shemot 30:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.30?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.30.16.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en)) responds that for the purpose of the census, all men counted were those who were 20 years old on the previous Rosh Hashana; **those who came of age during the year would not be counted until the next Rosh Hashana**
- [**Mizrachi**](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.30?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.30.16.1&lang2=bi&p3=Mizrachi%2C_Exodus.30.16.1&lang3=bi) adds that this assumes that **one of the many miracles that took place in the Wilderness** was that no one died between the first and second census, since dead men were surely not counted
- **Ramban** ([30:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.30.12?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Ramban_on_Exodus.30.12.1&lang2=bi)) disagrees, contenting that people were counted on the basis of their birthdays, not by their age on Rosh Hashana. Furthermore, he contends that there was a basic difference between eligibility for the two censuses: in the first, the Levites were surely counted, but the Torah excludes them from the census in Numbers, so that Rashi's reasoning cannot explain the identical counts. Ramban contends that there were indeed many who died between the tallies, but those who came of age made up not only for them but also for the Levites, who were not included in the second census. **That the two totals were identical was a coincidence**

Comment: Artscroll is misquoting the Ramban. He did not say (chas v'shalom?) that it was a coincidence. He said that the numbers were the same. Presumably he considered it to be an aspect of hashgacha.

Comment: I believe artscroll are basing themselves on the Ramban's statement "it so happened that their number corresponded exactly to that of those who died." (ואירע הדבר שהיו המשלימים כמנין המתים)

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. It happened - that doesn't mean that it was a coincidence. The Hebrew for _that_ might be מקרה, but I actually don't know if that means it either. That word might not be in their vocabulary.

Comment: See Ruth 2:3  וַיִּ֣קֶר מִקְרֶ֔הָ חֶלְקַ֤ת הַשָּׂדֶה֙ לְבֹ֔עַז. Every Jew knows that it wasn't a coincidence that she landed up in Boaz's field.

Answer (score 2):

It was the same generation. As the verses in Numbers 1:1-2 say when introducing the count:

> And the LORD spoke unto Moses in the wilderness of Sinai, in the tent of meeting, **on the first day of the second month, in the second year** after they were come out of the land of Egypt, saying:
>
> 'Take ye the sum of all the congregation of the children of Israel, by their families, by their fathers' houses, according to the number of names, every male, by their polls; ([Mechon-Mamre translation](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0401.htm), my emphasis)

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked the figure of people that entered the land, If you look at Numbers 26,51 there it states that in the plains of Moav when they were on the verge of entering the land of Israel, there were actually **601,730** men between 20 and 60

Comment: Oh wow- big mistake on my part. Thanks for this - my question above still stands.. lol

Answer (score 1):

I see Rashi's answer, the Ramban's questions and his two answers which rely on a huge coincidence that the number of people who dies equaled the number of people turning 20; and/or that includes the Leviim. Both equal exactly 603,550. Impossible statistically!!

Rabbi Moshe Duvid Casutto, aka Umberto Cassuto, who was an Orthodox Rabbi in Italy, then exiled by the Fascists in the early 40;s and came to Hebrew U in Israel, posits that the first census which took place on the 11th day of Tishrei, right after YK and the giving of the  second Luchos, and upon being commanded to build the Mishkan, which required silver for the sockets and , hence the Machtzis Hashekel, gave rise to 603,550. That very same census required them to write their names, Family affiliations, tribe, etc. on a pottery shard and give it to be counted. All on the 11th of Tishrei. They quickly counted the Machtzis Hashekel because they needed the silver, came to 603,550. Then, they slowly counted up the names on the pottery shards, completed it on 1st of Iyar and ths is the count in Bamidbar detailed by tribe! So its the very same count! With out Leviim. Thats why its exactly the same number 603,550. Brilliant answer. (There is also support somewhere that Kohanm are NOT allowed to give Machtzis Hashekel as then it would partially a Korbon Ychid and it has to davka be a Korban Tzibuur.)see Rabbi Willig who brings Cassuto's answer https://utj.org/viewpoints/parashat/numbers-numbers-and-more-numbers-do-they-all-add-up/

Just to add another source for the Cassuto answer.
https://www.hatanakh.com/sites/herzog/files/herzog/Yeshivat%20Har%20Etzion.pdf

Umberto, Moshe Duvid, Cassuto was a Gaon Olam and much under appreciated. Some might have difficulties with some of his explanations as they are creative, sometimes rely on support
of archeological records, and sometimes make reference to sources outside the Pale of Strict Orthodox thought. But then again, the same can be said of Rambam, Ramban, Ibn Ezra, Abarbanel, Zohar,  and many others. There are 70 faces/facets to Torah and it is all Divrei Elokim Chayim. A much under appreciated Scholar who suffered greatly for the Sake of Learning and Truth.  May his Holy Neshama be bound in the Bond of Eternal Life, Amen.

Comment: "_Both equal exactly 603,550. Impossible statistically_" (1) How is it [statistically impossible](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2049714)? (2) Is the second census resulting in 0 more counted than the first less probable/possible than it resulting in 5 more counted? ... than in 37 less counted? ... than in 222 more counted? ... than in 1003 less counted? Why?

Comment: See my comment above. The Ramban did not say that it was a coincidence and of course it was not.

Comment: @TamirEvan It's not "statistically impossible", but it is quite unlikely that the numbers match by chance. You're asking about other possibilities (5, -37,...) But you should be comparing the combined probability of _any one of those other possibilities happening_ (or many others), versus the probability of an exact match.

Comment: @MichoelR "_It's not 'statistically impossible', but_ ..." The answer's author is claiming tha it is. "... _it is quite unlikely that the numbers match by chance_ ." It may be odd, curious, notable, or even significant, but I wouldn't call it 'quite unlikely' (especially considering [the short time span between the counts](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100540/1368)).

Comment: @MichoelR "_But you should be comparing the combined probability of any one of those other possibilities happening (or many others), versus the probability of an exact match_ ." Why? The probability of _any_ specific possibility (for instance, the second count resulting in 5 more than the first) would always be smaller than the combined probability of the others. What would that prove?

Comment: @TamirEvan It's like saying, a card hand that's all hearts has exactly the same probability as any other specific hand. That's true, but one lumps together all the nondescript hands, and notes certain very specific possiblities as being extremely unlikely. Flipping a fair coin twenty times and getting all heads has exactly the same probability as HHTTHTHHHTHTTTHTHHHT, but one is astonishing and the other is just one of many nondescript possibilities. If you got twenty heads in a row, you would probably conclude that the coin is loaded.

Comment: @TamirEvan Btw, those two cases have about the same probability: Twenty heads in a row, or two randomly chosen six-digit numbers being identical: around one in a million.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Cassutto, I also found  the following in Shaarei Aharon Parshas Bamidbar. (Wish I could just cut and past but this doesn't accept images so you will have to look it up yourself if you like).
Tosfos, the Rivash and the Paanech Raza (Old Tosfos commentary on the Torah), all agree that there was only One Census that added to 603,550 and it took place at the same time. But one noted the total for the Chatzi Shekalim purpose in Ki sisa and one noted each individual member according to his Fathers ouse , Bamidabr.. Wish they taught me this in Yeshiva

Comment: You can paste images, sixth icon from the left on the ruler when editing a question. Shout if not clear